# What are best practices for handling store updates in a components' hierarchy?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

What are best practices for handling store updates in a complex components' hierarchy.
Consider a hierarchy of components (= a component that imports another that imports another) that can all access a Svelte store.

There is a button that is maybe 4 layers downs in that hierarchy. Say a click on that button should ultimately update my store. Should I write the function that does the `update` call in that deep component, or dispatch the event all the way up to the page route that includes the ancestor of that component and write the function there (or in another file I include in that route maybe)?

I'm using svelte-kit if that's relevant.
I'd be interested in comments/articles/resources that discuss the best practices in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of stores is precisely to avoid prop drilling or having to deal with event dispatch/handling.

Say you have a hierarchy or components A > B > C > D. If D is where the button that triggers the update is located, this is where you should import your store and update it, assuming all relevant data and update logic is available in that component. Then, wherever your update would have an impact and changes would need to be reflected (in A, B, C, or in any other component in your source tree for that matter), simply import and subscribe to that store.

On the other hand, if D is merely a functional button component (from, say, your UI library) and all the actual data and update logic is located in its parent C, then import the store and handle your update in C instead, and pass a reference to the update handler to D as a prop (something like `onClick` if it's a button, for example).

In short, the choice of where to import and update a store, and where to import and subscribe to a store, should be dictated primarily by logic and the nature and requirements of each of your components, without too much concern for hierarchy.

###### TL;DR

Handle the update where it makes the most sense. Don't clutter UI library components like buttons with case-specific update logic.